# Normal Mapped Models Render with render target background color acting as transparency and lighting Problem

Tags: directx, rendering, directx11

SOLVED.  See my comment below.

Originally I noticed some sort of transparency when rendering in Direct3D 11.  I noticed it was worse once I changed my background color to something other than black. I also created a simple exporter for Maya to output the model data.  The format is exactly as in the Rastertek's model format.  Most of my rendering code is more or less based off of the Rastertek website. I thought it was my exporter, but it renders just fine in the Rastertek executable. Here's a picutre of what I am talking about.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2j5qukam32h2tgc/Direct3D%20Model.png

The model is a simple cylinder with a cone sticking into it from the top.
I thought it had something do with the normals, or a culling problem, but I am unsure.

Also, I am still new to some of this.  I will post code if needed.

EDIT:  Color/Lighting transparency is working now.

Here is my Depth initialization code:

```
    ID3D11Texture2D* backBufferPtr;

    // Get the pointer to the back buffer.
    HRESULT result = m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&backBufferPtr);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Create the render target view with the back buffer pointer.
    result = m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(backBufferPtr, NULL, &m_renderTargetView);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Release pointer to the back buffer as we no longer need it.
    backBufferPtr->Release();
    backBufferPtr = 0;

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthBufferDesc;
    // Initialize the description of the depth buffer.
    ZeroMemory(&depthBufferDesc, sizeof(depthBufferDesc));

    // Set up the description of the depth buffer.
    depthBufferDesc.Width = width;
    depthBufferDesc.Height = height;
    depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    depthBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    // Create the texture for the depth buffer using the filled out description.
    result = m_device->CreateTexture2D(&depthBufferDesc, NULL, &m_depthStencilBuffer);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthStencilDesc;
    // Initialize the description of the stencil state.
    ZeroMemory(&depthStencilDesc, sizeof(depthStencilDesc));

    // Set up the description of the stencil state.
    depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
    depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
    depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;

    depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
    depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
    depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;

    // Stencil operations if pixel is front-facing.
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    // Stencil operations if pixel is back-facing.
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    // Create the depth stencil state.
    result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, &m_depthStencilState);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Set the depth stencil state.
    m_deviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_depthStencilState, 1);

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc;
    // Initailze the depth stencil view.
    ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(depthStencilViewDesc));

    // Set up the depth stencil view description.
    depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
    depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    // Create the depth stencil view.
    result = m_device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilBuffer, &depthStencilViewDesc, &m_depthStencilView);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Bind the render target view and depth stencil buffer to the output render pipeline.
    m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_renderTargetView, m_depthStencilView);

    D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rasterDesc;
    // Setup the raster description which will determine how and what polygons will be drawn.
    rasterDesc.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;
    rasterDesc.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
    rasterDesc.DepthBias = 0;
    rasterDesc.DepthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
    rasterDesc.DepthClipEnable = true;
    rasterDesc.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID;
    rasterDesc.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
    rasterDesc.MultisampleEnable = false;
    rasterDesc.ScissorEnable = false;
    rasterDesc.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.0f;

    // Create the rasterizer state from the description we just filled out.
    result = m_device->CreateRasterizerState(&rasterDesc, &m_rasterState);
    if(FAILED(result))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Now set the rasterizer state.
    m_deviceContext->RSSetState(m_rasterState);

    // Setup the viewport for rendering.
    m_viewport.Width = (float)width;
    m_viewport.Height = (float)height;
    m_viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    m_viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    m_viewport.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
    m_viewport.TopLeftY = 0.0f;

    // Create the viewport.
    m_deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &m_viewport);

    // Setup the projection matrix.
    float fieldOfView = (float)XM_PI / 4.0f;
    float screenAspect = (float)width / (float)height;

    // Create the projection matrix for 3D rendering.
    m_screenDepth = 1000.0f;
    m_projectionMatrix = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( fieldOfView, screenAspect, 0.1f, m_screenDepth );

    // Initialize the world matrix to the identity matrix.
    m_worldMatrix =XMMatrixIdentity();

    return true;
```

Updated Picture:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/me86svum7cep1ti/D3D11%20Picture.PNG

Comment: Do you write the color.a value in the pixel shader? Make sure that it is set as one where you don't want transparency. Where color is the final color of the pixel.

Comment: Ok, that helped with the color issue. Thanks!  But, I can still sort of see thru the model at the "cone" part though.

Comment: Do you have depth testing enabled?

Comment: Yes, I do have it enabled.  I posted the code above.

Comment: I think I have fixed it.  I am using DirectX Tool Kit as well, and now that I got the graphics debugger to work, I noticed that the depth testing was being disabled.  I can only assume it is a result of using SpriteBatch to render text and other 2D components. So simply setting the depthStencilState at the begining of my render function, it fixed it.  Thanks for the help, you kind of pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad it worked. :)

Comment: It's OK to add your own answer with the final solution and mark it as accepted. That makes it easier for future readers to find it.

Comment: Ah, Didn't know that.  I'll go ahead and add that then.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have fixed it. I am using DirectX Tool Kit as well, and now that I got the graphics debugger to work, I noticed that the depth testing was being disabled. I can only assume it is a result of using SpriteBatch to render text and other 2D components. So simply setting the depthStencilState at the begining of my render function, it fixed it.